# Using sum in withColumn pyspark / python

Tags: python, pyspark, sum, aggregate

I need your help in a small issue, which I actually solved in a manual way, but I would like to get it "right"

Data:

| customer_id | gender |
| --- | --- |
| abc | m |
| def | w |

etc.

Now it gets aggreaget the following way:

```
gender_count = data.groupBy('gender').agg(F.countDistinct('customer_id').alias('amount'))
```

gender_count:

| gender | amount |
| --- | --- |
| m | 4 |
| w | 6 |

Now, I would like to creat a new column with the total number of customers in order to compute the share of the individual genders.
However, I could not find a function that works with "withColumn". So what I do is to sum up the number of customers before and insert it as a literal value:

```
gender_count = gender_count.withColumn('total', F.lit(10)).withColumn('share', (F.col('amount') / F.col('total')))
```

Result:

| gender | amount | total | share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m | 4 | 10 | 0.4 |
| w | 6 | 10 | 0.6 |

Do you have any idea how i could replace the **F.lit(10)**? That would save me one manual step and a potential source of error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the count() on the dataframe.

```
total_items = data.count()

gender_count = gender_count.withColumn('total', F.lit(total_items)).withColumn('share', (F.col('amount') / F.col('total')))
```

Comment: Thanks, it would solve my problem.
However, I encountered a case where I hade to aggregate (sum) also with filtering. Then I could not use "F.lit" because I had data frames as results. What I did then is to crossJoin the tables which gave me the column with the constant result. 

Would have .collect( ) worked? My computations were on a very large data set so I did not experiment, because it have lasted a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` as a **window function** before aggregation to count all records.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
    .withColumn('count', F.count('*').over(W.partitionBy(F.lit(1))))
    .groupBy('gender', 'count')
    .agg(F.countDistinct('customer_id').alias('amount'))
    .withColumn('share', F.col('amount') / F.col('count'))
    .show()
)

+------+-----+------+-----+
|gender|count|amount|share|
+------+-----+------+-----+
|     m|   10|     4|  0.4|
|     w|   10|     6|  0.6|
+------+-----+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution suggestion.